# Polymer tests break after importing official paper libraries

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, html-imports

### Question

I've created a polymer element using the CLI. This gives me an element entry and basic tests. Those tests are running fine.

After including `paper-input` or `iron-icons`, the tests in Firefox still work. The same tests in Chrome, however, break with a strange error.

How can I import elements without breaking the tests? The same issue occurred when importing iron elements. Chrome in production and CI is very important to me.

### reproduction:

Polymer CLI 1.6.0

Polymer 2.5.0

> user@randy-ubuntu:~/IdeaProjects/music-app-header$ `polymer init`
>
> Which starter template would you like to use: `polymer-2-element`
>
> info: Running template polymer-2-element...
>
> Element name: `music-app-header`
>
> Brief description of the element: `music-app-header`

`polymer test`

```
Test run ended with great success

chrome 65 (2/0/0)                       firefox 59 (2/0/0)
```

---

#### Changing the code:

`bower install paper-button`

Adding the paper-button import as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="music-app-header">
```

`polymer test`

```
  Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    <unknown> at   <unknown> at /components/music-app-header/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-module.html:137:0
    <unknown> at   <unknown> at /components/music-app-header/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-module.html:142:0

chrome 65                Tests failed: 1 failed tests

Test run ended in failure: 1 failed tests

chrome 65 (2/0/1)                       firefox 59 (2/0/0)


Error: 1 failed tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with a dependency issue.

Instead of installing `paper-button`, you're supposed to install `PolymerElements/paper-button`.

`bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-button`